# Eloquent custom "belongs to" relationship on multiple tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen, eloquent-relationship

I have the following DB structure:

- Table **Vehicles**: id, car_id, plane_id
- Table **Cars**: id, model...
- Table **Planes**: id, model...

When a new record added to the table **Vehicles**, if it is a **Car**, the *car_id* will be set, while the *plane_id* will be left empty, and vice-versa, *I know it's a bad structure*, but it is legacy and I can't change it.

So I want to define a relationship in the Vehicle model where it can retrieve the Car object or the Plane object according to which key is empty, the *car_id* or the *plane_id*. And btw, I've already defined two relationships that will retrieve the **Car** object and the **Plane** object separately.

```
public function carVehicle()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Car::class, 'car_id');
}

public function planeVehicle()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Plane::class, 'plane_id');
}
```

Comment: So, what error are you getting? Instead of saving `car_id`,`plane_id` you can manage it by Polymorphic relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This would be best handled by a `Polymorphic` relationship (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationship for details), but there's ways around this if your current model doesn't match the structure and you can't change it.

You could have a third method that adds both to a `Collection` and returns the `first()` one (since you say one of `car_id` or `plane_id` will always be `null`):

`Vehicle.php`:

```
public function getChildVehicleAttribute(){
  return collect([$this->carVehicle, $this->planeVehicle])
  ->filter(function($record) {
    return $record != null;
  })->first();
}
```

Then, you'd access via the following query:

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::with(['carVehicle', 'planeVehicle'])->first()->child_vehicle;
// OR
$vehicles = Vehicle::with(['carVehicle', 'planeVehicle'])->get();
foreach($vehicles AS $vehicle){
  $childVehicle = $vehicle->child_vehicle;
  // dd($childVehicle, etc.)
}
```

The `with()` clause would eagerload both relationships so `$this->carVehicle` and `$this->planeVehicle` don't trigger additional database calls, and calling `child_vehicle` on any `Vehicle` instance would return either a `Car` or a `Plane` (or `null` if neither is defined)